# Need help reading from SQLite database for Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursor

I have read through many sites and tutorials and have been unable to solve my problem.  I have an application that works until I try to read from my database (it opens it just fine).  I know its not the right way to do things but I have two global strings that I pass from my main activity to my DataBaseHelper class (`DB_TABLE` and `spinnerPipeLengthText`).  When I call the following line of code to retrieve the data from all the columns in a specific row my application crashes.

```
Cursor cursorData = myDataBase.query(CSSTPipeSizingActivity.DB_TABLE, null, 
            CSSTPipeSizingActivity.spinnerPipeLengthText, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Here is my complete `getData` method:

```
public Cursor getData() {

    Cursor cursorData = myDataBase.query(CSSTPipeSizingActivity.DB_TABLE, null, 
            CSSTPipeSizingActivity.spinnerPipeLengthText, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursorData != null)
        cursorData.moveToFirst();

    cursorData.moveToFirst();
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize15.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToNext();        
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize19.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToFirst();
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize25.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToNext();        
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize31.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToFirst();
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize37.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToNext();        
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize46.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
    cursorData.moveToNext();        
    CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize62.setText(cursorData.getString(1));

    cursorData.close();
    return cursorData;
} // end method getData
```

As you can see from my code, I am trying to take the data and input it straight into text views in the `main.xml` file. I don't know if this is possible but that will be for me to figure out later.  Right now I need to get the data.

Here is my logcat:

```
03-12 19:23:33.587: D/AndroidRuntime(20191): Shutting down VM
03-12 19:23:33.587: W/dalvikvm(20191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skyesmechanical.CSSTPipeSizing/com.skyesmechanical.CSSTPipeSizing.CSSTPipeSizingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at com.skyesmechanical.CSSTPipeSizing.DataBaseHelper.getData(DataBaseHelper.java:173)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at com.skyesmechanical.CSSTPipeSizing.CSSTPipeSizingActivity.onCreate(CSSTPipeSizingActivity.java:105)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-12 19:23:33.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20191):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you' re closing your cursor and then trying to return it... not gonna work too well that way.  Either close the cursor and return nothing or return the cursor.

You also keep iterating over the first couple entries when you do movetofirst, movetonext, then movetofirst again.

I also believe your getString needs a little help.

Here's how I go about it:

```
titleTxt.setText(eventedit.getString(eventedit
    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(AttendanceDB.EVENT_NAME)));
```

`titleTxt` is a TextView reference I set earlier.
`eventEdit` is the cursor I'm wanting to get the info from (and created earlier)
`AttendanceDB` is my DB adapter class
`EVENT_NAME` is the column name variable I set in my DB adapter class

**EDIT**

Ok, now that I re-read your question, I realize I was answering the wrong portion.  The problem is your query is messed up.  I think it should be more like this:

```
Cursor cursorData = myDataBase.query(CSSTPipeSizingActivity.DB_TABLE, null,  
    COLUMN_ID + "=" + CSSTPipeSizingActivity.spinnerPipeLengthText, null, null, null, null, null);
```

You need to tell the query what column to search for the info you want (CSSTPipeSizingActivity.spinnerPipeLengthText).  So replace COLUMN_ID with your column name or the variable for it and you should be good to go.

You really should review the info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), especially the various query method and their required parameters.

Comment: I get an error if i try to switch the return and close around...the movetofirst and movetonext was my bad on copining and pasting.

Comment: Of course you get an error, nothing happens after `return x` (it's a lot like break in that regard).  The point being either you need to return the cursor, in which case you shouldn't close it, or you need to close it and not return anything.  I've modified my answer to show how I'm doing it in a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from your logcat that the error is a NullPointerException at line 173. Without line numbers in your code, it's hard to know exactly what the issue is in this case, but my guess is that line 173 is the cursorData.moveToFirst() that isn't in the if-statement.

Consider the case where cursorData is null -

You check that cursorData is not null, and if that's the case, you call moveToFirst(). But then you call moveToFirst() in the next line; this will happen whether cursorData is null or not.

A common design pattern would be for getData to simply return the cursor, and for the calling method to handle the extraction. This could look something like:

{
    ...
    if (cursorData != null)
        cursorData.moveToFirst();
    return cursorData;
}

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, think you can put all your code using Cursor in IF statement:

```
    if (cursorData != null){
        cursorData.moveToFirst();
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize15.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToNext();        
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize19.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToFirst();
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize25.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToNext();        
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize31.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToFirst();
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize37.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToNext();        
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize46.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.moveToNext();        
        CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize62.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
        cursorData.close();
    }
```

Second, you may check below code b/c you move to next twice:

```
cursorData.moveToNext();        
CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize46.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
cursorData.moveToNext();        
CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize62.setText(cursorData.getString(1));
```

Finally, use your setText with a String casting for all setText method:

```
CSSTPipeSizingActivity.textViewSize15.setText("" + cursorData.getString(1));
```